# Google currency conversion characters not retrieved through url

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io, currency

for currency conversion i have used [a link](http://www.google.com/finance/converter) and used in code $url="http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$currFrom&to=$currInto";

```
function getHtmlCodeViaFopen($url)

{
       $ci =& get_instance();
    $returnStr="";

    $default_currency_code=$ci->config->item('default_currency_code');

    if($default_currency_code!="USD")
    {
        $fp=fopen($url, "r") or die("ERROR: Failed to open $url for reading via this script.");
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $returnStr.=fgetc($fp);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return $returnStr;
    }
```

now the url not responding in my server but works fine in my url i used preg match to retrieve the characters from that url

It shows the die error ERROR: Failed to open http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=40&from=USD&to=USD for reading via this script. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens even with this?

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=EUR&to=USD");
```

print $data to see if data has been received.

**EDITED:**

Ok, call this also. What did you get?

```
echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
```

Comment: i have printed through var_dump($data); its returning as bool(false). Its returning nothing rite.

Comment: I tried that it has returned "0", it should be 1 or "On" rite?.

Comment: I ll change it to 1 or on and get back to you @vlzvl

Comment: Thanks vlzvl i changed the server settings it works fine.any reference to configure the php.ini on runtime.

Comment: you can have this in your .htaccess next time:   
php_flag allow_url_fopen On
or in your php.ini:
allow_url_fopen = On